# Cannot access files under resource directory in a jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-io, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

Basically working on a spring project that is trying to leverage google api. To do so I need to access the StoredCredentials file, which is follows this path:

src/main/resources/xyz@gmail.com/drive-tokens/StoredCredentials

To that end,

```
private FileDataStoreFactory getDriveTokens() throws IOException {
    return new FileDataStoreFactory(resourceLoader.getResource(CLASSPATH + emailAddressForDrive + Constants.TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH).getFile());
}
```

here CLASSPATH="classpath:", TOKENS directory = "/drive-tokens/"

This code works fine locally but doesn't work on prod or other testing servers. I am being forced to hard code the file path on those environments to execute this. The error thrown on servers:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [xyz@gmail.com/drive-tokens/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:
```

The main issue here is that FileDataStoreFactory requires a File object and not an input stream. There are plenty of questions of similar to this but the answers there don't really apply to the constraints here.

Edit - More context on this

I am trying to authorize my code to login to the account and access the drive

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, Constants.SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(getDriveTokens())//tokens
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
```

Here, both the client secrets and the drive tokens are being used and make it necessary that the file type be DataStoreFactory

Comment: Don't know the API but why does it have to be that type of DataStoreFactory?

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check edits

Comment: I shouldn't really be commenting too much on this but it just got my attention. My question is simply if there's a DataStoreFactory why can't it be a MemoryDataStoreFactory loaded via resources?